# How to add an element that is the child of several foreign key relations without touching the parent elements

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL in C# on 2 elements (for this question say they are a game and a console), having a one-to-many relationship  (one type of console can be used to play many games).

Let's say this is my Game Class:

```
public class Game {
public int GameID {get; set;} ///this is the PK
public int ConsoleID {get; set;} ///this is the FK
public string Title {get; set;} ///this is the title of the game.
...
}
```

and this is my Console Class:

```
public class Console {
public int ConsoleID {get; set;} ///this is the PK
public string ConsoleName {get; set;} ///this is the name of the console
public int GenerationNumber {get; set;} ///this is the generation of the console. e.g: The    Nintendo 64 is a 3rd generation console (after NES and SNES)
...
}
```

In the DBML File, i have an association between the two classes:
Cardinality: OneToMany
Child Property is Internal and is called Games (no modifiers)
Parent Property is Public and is Console.
The Participating Properties are obviously Game.ConsoleID and Console.ConsoleID.
Unique is set to false.

I want to add a Game to the Database. Upon doing so, I set all the properties to their corresponding values. Assuming the game is an XBOX360 game, Game.Console.*propertyname* will display info about the XBOX360.

However, when I use a service and repository to add the Game to the Database (SQL Server 08), I get a DuplicateKeyException on the Console. Because of this, I assume this means it is trying to add the already existing information about the console to the console table. Obviously, I would not like this to happen.

Here is what I have tried so far:

Attempt #1:

```
Game.Console = null; //fails - set the ID to 0, and tried to remove the relationship)
```

Attempt #2:

```
Game.Console = null;
Game.ConsoleID = 6; //fails - ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException is thrown
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to lookup and add in the console to the game before binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with Linq it is very much a read and replay model.  Try retrieving the related entities from Linq first, then setting those properties accordingly. Linq should then know the proper correlations and the duplicate FK exceptions should go away.